# List items copied to another similar list

Tags: sharepoint-designer, designer-workflow, list-view, forms-7

I have two lists that are similar but kept separate But on the same site, since I've had an issue with associating "add," "edit," and "view" forms to certain list views that correspond with that party.  So, my idea was to make two separate lists with fields A-M in one list, and the other list has fields D-Z in it.  This way i can have two parties use two sets of forms and not share certain information.

My question is how can i get list 1 with fields A-M to populate list 2 with fields D-M once list 1 is completed and approved?  I see several different features in SP Designer but am getting stuck.  Any ideas?

Comment: Keep it in the same list, and use JavaScript to hide/show fields based on the user (in the new/edit/display forms).  I don't see a reason to split the list.  There are other things you can do before you split the list.

Answer (score 1):

You can use SharePoint designer to Create custom Workflow at List 1 to create/update list items fields Z-M at List 2.

To do that follow the mentioned steps below:

- At action from the above ribbon > List Action
- Select Create / Update list item

[image]

- Click on this list and select your list 2

[image]

Comment: I am also here if you need more clarification

Comment: Will I have to set the fx function or will it automatically know what fields to fill in from the corresponding columns?  Right now i'm following the instructions and i'm adding all the fields i want to carry over.

Comment: you specify what's the field that you need to update it in the updated list

Comment: I think i'm getting it.  But why did it only pre-set a few of the fields in the Create list time menu and place an asterisk next to each one?  Are these only required fields in the list?

Comment: If I understand you , yes, it's required field. Are you have any more question ?

Comment: Last one I hope.  "then Create Listm in (list)"  is followed by "Output to VARIABLE: Create2"

Comment: what does that mean?

Comment: the output variable is variable to save the specific status of the output of the current step  to check it in your next condition and apply the next steps based on your requirement

Comment: read more about variable here https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Use-variables-in-workflows-db87c14d-bc07-46c4-8936-9c55aed04204

Comment: Dear @CHussong I tried to help you so Please don't forget to set this as answer in case it's solved your issue to close this question :)