# How do I get these labels off these fields? They show up on the editform page too

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-designer

On some pages where I use 2007 this happens?It does not happen on 2010.

Anytime I create a custom edit form these label fields appear and won't come off.I scoured the web and no real answers,. How do I remove this?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to add the following two styles to your `editform`that will hide these label fields.

```
    <style type="text/css">

    .ms-formfieldvaluecontainer {
        margin:0px;
        border: 0px;
        padding:0px;
        border-style:hidden;
    }

    .ms-formfieldlabelcontainer {
        display: none ! important;
    }
    </style>
```

Check also similer issue [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10458219/sharepoint2k7-custom-list-editform-annoying-field-labels-how-to-remove)

Comment: sheesh, give the man some time to try out your answer before bugging him about marking the answer.

Comment: Dear @teylyn thanks for your hint, but really I have more answers that the questioner says to me thanks it's solved my issue and not set it as answer , I only tried to remember him as I mention above I said ,"take your time to check the above solution" , if you have another method to overcome this behaviour please tell me !

Comment: You can't force them to accept an answer. Everybody who answers here has the same issue, so please wait at least until the OP tells you that your answer solved their issue. Then a gentle reminder is OK, but not 2 minutes after you posted. That comes across as a bit greedy.

Comment: You are right,  he has full free to do that or not , but what's the issue for this kind reminder , I see more answers at TechNet and here say that in his answer not as a comment as I do.  also, should you tell me why you consider this as a type of greedy ?!! Is he give me money !! I only tried to help him and I think  he also has the same feeling to help me but sometimes he needs to know How to do that !? I told him  "please set this as answer" only if it's solved his issue and this is not related to any greedy ! it's a type of appreciation to my effort, thanks again for the hint !!

Comment: this a sample of questions that I didn't mention any type of reminder until he told me "Your the best, thanks for all the help" and then I tried to tell him please set this as answer to close this question see his response !!! http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/188044/list-items-copied-to-another-similar-list/188046#comment198484_188046

Comment: Calm down. You can't force anyone to accept the answer.  I know what I'm talking about. [See here](http://meta.sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/853/are-sharepoint-se-users-lazy-voters). Just stop bugging people. It creates unnecessary noise and you come across as a bully, not helpful. You're on the path to earn the Unsung Hero badge, so that's something to be proud of. Calm down and stop pushing people. If you have a problem, take it to Meta. Also, point people to the [Tour], where they can see what you want them to do. But please, only after they told you that your answer rocks.

Comment: One more thing before this goes to chat: You know stuff about SharePoint. Why are you here? Do you want to help people find solutions to their SharePoint problems or do you want to collect reputation points? What is more important to you? Helping or getting recognition? It's a mindset thing.

Comment: If you are after recognition points, go to another site, because people here are bad when it comes to voting and accepting answers. If you want to continue contributing here, just accept that there will be a low acceptance and upvoting rate and get on with your life.

Comment: Stop with the comment almost immediately after posting your answer with the upvote/answer nonsense, this isn't the MSDN forums where that stuff slides. It is bad form, one mod already mentioned this to you.

Comment: Ok, I don't do it again. , I appreciate community rules and policy , and thanks @EricAlexander and thanks again teylyn for your valuable hint.